# saving gameObject layer always ends up as default (Unity + VS)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-2017, layer

So, I've been following this guide: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RQyfHmf7v9s
To make a space shooter game.

The idea is that two objects under layer "Enemy" won't collide, But when the object under layer "Player" collides with "Enemy" it becomes part of "invulnerable" layer that doesn't collide with anything.

but it seems that one line at the code (this one:)

```
            gameObject.layer = correctLayer;
```

turns my object into "Default" layer every time.
this is the code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
[AddComponentMenu("WaterEffects/ForCamera")]
public class HitHandler : MonoBehaviou {

public int health = 1; //Object health

float invulnTimer = 0.25f; //Time in which the gameObject is invulnerable
int correctLayer; // save the original layer of the object

void start()
{
    correctLayer = gameObject.layer;    
    gameObject.SetActive(true);
}

void OnTriggerEnter2D()
{
    Debug.Log("Trigger!");
    health--;
    invulnTimer = 2f;
    gameObject.layer = 10; //put object in invulnerable layer
}
// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    invulnTimer -= Time.deltaTime;
    if (invulnTimer <= 0)
    {
        gameObject.layer = correctLayer; //returns object to original layer (doesnt work)
    }
    if (health <= 0)
    {
        Die();
    }
}
void Die()
{
    Destroy(gameObject); // Destroys object
}
}
```

I have no idea why the start function doesn't save the right layer, even though in unity i have defined the objects as their reflective layers.

Note: I have made the objects Kinematic and checked IsTrigger. When the first mentioned line of code is not in use it does work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be **void Start()** not void start().
Be aware of those capital letters.

Comment: Thank you so much, I feel so stupid. Cant believe I've been on that for hours becuase one Capital letter...

Comment: Ever debug is your friend. If have a problem, first check where your code reached.

Comment: @joreldraw since its VS + Unity it seems debugging isnt working (since the game is in Unity and VS is just for writing it), or i might be missing something.

Comment: you can attach VS to Unity and debug. yes your missing something :)